# Ubuntu 13.04 on a preinstalled Windows 8 system w/ UEFI

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I've been trying to get Ubuntu 13.04 to work on my desktop that came with Windows 8 pre-installed and the UEFI system.  Needless to say, I'm having trouble.  The desktop in question is an HP Pavilion P6-2738.  It also seems that I need to get drivers somehow for the ethernet adapter, but that's a whole different thread.

I went into the BIOS/UEFI editor and disabled secure boot, enabled legacy mode.  During installation, Ubuntu says it can't install GRUB2, no matter where I tell it to install it.  I'm using the "something else" option and defining my own partitions.  I have a seperate 160GiB drive I'm using for it, so maybe that's the issue.  I don't know.  Any and all help is appreciated, as it's late, and I'm out of ideas.

I'm trying to get it to dual-boot btw.  Probably worth mentioning :P

Update:  At the end of the installation, it says it's completely removing, and occasionally purging stuff.  I got it to install grub to a separate partition.  I'm not worried about getting an OS selection screen yet, but just going directly into the boot selection screen and selecting my secondary drive to boot from, I get "OS failed to load".

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows system is installed in UEFI GPT partitions. All hard drive is formatted as GPT, so when you trying to boot as Legacy, you are not able to make dual boot.

Why don't you use UEFI-boot for installing Ubuntu? It supports EFI partitions as well.
It differs a bit from Legacy mode booting, but still works good.

Check this out

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: When I try installing it with UEFI enabled, I get the black/grey text screen for asking if I want to try or install it, and then whatever option I choose the screen just goes to black and nothing happens.

Comment: have you tried other Linux distros?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a lack of **BIOS-Boot partition**.

Your disk is GPT type, and you disabled EFI, so you need to create such a BIOS-Boot partition during the disk partitioning. See [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#BIOS-Boot_or_EFI_partition_.28required_on_GPT_disks.29) for more info.